# i am using pythone 3.8 when i try to install pyaudio it shows error

Tags: python

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\varun\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\varun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q5dyie_1\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\varun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q5dyie_1\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ttcu7vjc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q5dyie_1\pyaudio\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\varun\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\varun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q5dyie_1\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\varun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q5dyie_1\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ttcu7vjc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\varun\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\varun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q5dyie_1\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\varun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q5dyie_1\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ttcu7vjc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q5dyie_1\pyaudio\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\varun\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\varun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q5dyie_1\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\varun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q5dyie_1\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ttcu7vjc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The error and solution are very clear `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.", can you try setting it to see if it solves your problem?

You can find installation instructions here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Good luck!